# autorestart daemons

Tags: debian, process-management

I use debian, same service `/usr/bin/something` starts same daemon with different config file:

```
#!/bin/sh

# veriables
service1=on
service9=on
service45=on
[...]

/usr/bin/something /home/user/conf1/something
/usr/bin/something /home/user/conf9/something
/usr/bin/something /home/user/conf45/something
```

from command line I see with `ps`:

```
user 123 0.0 0.0 0.0 pts/2 /usr/bin/something /home/user/conf1/something
user 124 0.0 0.0 0.0 pts/2 /usr/bin/something /home/user/conf9/something
user 125 0.0 0.0 0.0 pts/2 /usr/bin/something /home/user/conf45/something
```

Sometimes linux kills one these and I need to automatically restart. These services really are less or more 100 but does not consecutive, so I need to check with `ps` which are not started and restart.

If os kills (e.g.)

```
user 123 0.0 0.0 0.0 pts/2 /usr/bin/something /home/user/conf1/something
```

the script should "scan" with `ps` which daemons are off - in this case it is

```
/home/user/conf1/something
```

only - and hence restart it.

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to tell answerers _what operating system this is_.  Then they stand at least a chance of telling you how to use whatever service management your operating system provides.

Comment: It would also be interesting to know what in "linux kills one of these" and for what reason.

Comment: depends: sometime in dmesg I see "out of memory", although there's some free ram :-/